# Different notions of embedded metric in a hypersurface

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

Let there be a metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ on a manifold $\bf{M}$ of dimension $d$. I want to find the metric on an hypersurface $\Sigma$ of dimension $d-1$ parametrized by some coordinates $y^i=y^i(x^\mu)$ where $i=1,\dots,d-1$ and $\mu=1,\dots,d$. On one hand, I can do the *pullback of the metric tensor* to get

\begin{equation}
h_{ij}=\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial y^i}\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial y^j}g_{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}

Also, many textbooks use the *induced metric*, defined as

\begin{equation}
\gamma_{\mu\nu}=g_{\mu\nu}-n^2 n_\mu n_\nu
\end{equation}

where $n^\mu$ is a orthonormal vector to $\Sigma$. $\gamma_{\mu\nu}$ also serves as the projector operator onto $\Sigma$.

What's the physical meaning of each object? How are they related?

Comment: They’re equivalent (assuming your submanifold is non-degenerate, ef spacelike). The second equation tells you how the pullback is related, via the presence of a normal vector field, to the ambient metric.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! How do we deal with the fact that one has indices from 1 to 3 and the other one from 1 to 4?

Comment: Let’s do this coordinate-free because it’s much easier. Fix a point $p$ on the submanifold, and two vectors $v,w$ which are tangent to the bigger manifold at $p$. Now how can we simplify the inner product $g(v,w)$? Obviously we split up the vectors into their components tangent and normal to the submanifold (this is where I use non-degeneracy of the submanifold). So write $v=v_1+v_2$ and likewise with $w$. Then $g(v,w)=g(v_1,w_1)+g(v_2,w_2)= h(v_1,w_1)+g(v_2,w_2)$, where $h$ is the pullback.

Comment: To reconcile indices, ask yourself, $v_1$ is tangent to submanifold, so if I use a submanifold-chart to express the components of this vector, then I only need that many indices (in your case $d-1$). For the normal portion $v_2$, you’re using all coordinates of the ambient manifold, so you need $d$ of them.